# Filtering rows in Spark Dataframe based on multiple values in a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Define a DataFrame with the following rows:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(name='bob', income=2.0), Row(name='john', income=1.0), Row(name='evan', income=0.0), Row(name='wei', income=3.0)])
```

How can I select rows with values in the list `[0.0, 3.0]`. I realize I can do something like:

```
>>> df.where((df.income==0.0) | (df.income==3.0)).collect()
>>> [Row(income=0.0, name='evan'), Row(income=3.0, name='wei')]
```

But that won't scale when the DataFrame has millions of rows and the list of possible values to filter on is much larger. I was hoping there might be an operation like `in`:

```
>>> df.where(df.income in [0.0, 3.0]).collect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 427, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Clearly that isn't defined. Any thoughts? Is there a simple `udf` that could handle this where I could pass in a list?

Comment: Well you can create a `DataFrame` to store those values and then do a `inner join`.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Brilliant! I was overthinking it.